# XML serialization of objects with envelope in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I need to serialize objects to XML in C#. The objects should be wrapped in an envelope. For that, I've created the following `Envelope` class:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Person))]
public class Envelope
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public object WrappedObject { get; set; }
}
```

I use the following code to serialize the class:

```
string fileName = ...;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName);
try
{
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, <instance of envelope>);
}
finally
{
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

When I assign an object of type `Person` to `WrappedObject`, I get the following XML:

```
<Envelope>
    <SomeValue>...</SomeValue>
    <WrappedObject xsi:type="Person">
        ....
    </WrappedObject>
</Envelope>
```

The problem is, I would like the tag for the wrapped object to be named after the actual class that I pass in. For example, if I assign an instance of `Person` to `WrappedObject`, I'd like the XML to look like the following:

```
<Envelope>
    <SomeValue>...</SomeValue>
    <Person>
        ....
    </Person>
</Envelope>
```

If I assign an instance of `Animal`, I'd like to get

```
<Envelope>
    <SomeValue>...</SomeValue>
    <Animal>
        ....
    </Animal>
</Envelope>
```

How would I achieve that?

**EDIT**

Actually I've simplified my example a little... The wrapped object is actually wrapped again:

```
public class Envelope
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public Wrapper Wrap { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(Person))]
public class Wrapper
{
    public object WrappedObject { get; set; }
}
```

How would I handle this using the attributes override?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [attribute override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx). I am using it *heavily* as I do a lot of custom serialisation.

This is a rough untested snippet but should point you in the right direction:

```
XmlAttributes attributes = new XmlAttributes();
XmlAttributeOverrides xmlAttributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
attributes.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("Person", t));
xmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof(Person), "WrappedObject", attributes);
XmlSerializer myserialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope), xmlAttributeOverrides);
```

Comment: OK, I see how this works, but I must admit I've simplified my example a little ;-) Would you mind taking a look at my modified version above?

Comment: The same code should work. You should not even need the `XmlInclude`

Comment: Hm, when I strip the `XmlInclude` I get an exception that says something like "Unexpected type..., use XmlInclude or SoapInclude...".

Comment: OK you perhaps can add the `XmlInclude` using the `XmlAttributeOverrides` itself and make it neater.

Comment: Oops, I copied/pasted your code and there's an additional "Space"-character after the property name `WrappedObject`. I accidentially left this in. When I remove it, everything works as expected! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: As soon as I removed the additional "Space"-character, I also didn't need the `XmlInclude` attribute anymore.

Comment: I though so since we are providing the type in there. Thanks for the update